# Change Div background color using HEX value stored in json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

(**I updated my code to remove the br from info2**)

I want to use jQuery to read a JSON file (it contains a color name and its hex value) and load the color names into a drop-down select (I got this part working). Then I want the **div next to the drop-down select to change to the selected color when the user changes the value of the drop-down select**. How do I change the div background color to that of the hex value for the color the user selects?

My page:

[image]

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var JSON_Response;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON('Colors.json', function (data) {
            JSON_Response = data;  



            var mySelect = document.getElementById("selColor");

            for (i = 0; i < JSON_Response.Colors.length; i++) {
                var myOption = document.createElement("option");
                myOption.text = JSON_Response.Colors[i].colorName;
                myOption.value = i;
                try {

                    mySelect.add(myOption, mySelect.options[null]);
                }
                catch (e) {
                    mySelect.add(myOption, null);
                }
            } 

        }); 

        $("#selColor").change(function () {
            var myIndex = $("#selColor").val();
            $("#showColor").attr("src", JSON_Response.Colors[myIndex].hex);

            var info = JSON_Response.Colors[myIndex].colorName + "<br />";
            info += JSON_Response.Colors[myIndex].hex+ "<br />";
            var info2 = JSON_Response.Colors[myIndex].hex;
            $("#divDisplay").html(info).css({'background-color' : '#' + info2});


        }); 
    });     

    </script>
```

Comment: Take a good look at your code. Notice that `info2` would be something like `fefefe<br />`, does that look like a valid color to you ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't append `<br />` to `info2`, since it's supposed to just contain a color code.

```
var info2 = JSON_Response.Colors[myIndex].hex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have it.  The error is in the background-color value you're setting for the div.

```
$("#divDisplay").html(info).css({'background-color' : '#' + info2});
```

should read

```
$("#divDisplay").html(info).css({'background-color' : '#' + JSON_Response.Colors[myIndex].hex});
```

---

[Basic working fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EricLease/tn6v4pzc/)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Click me</button><br/>
    <div id="myDiv" style="height:400px;width:400px;">
    </div>

    <script>
    var hexChars = "ABCDEF0123456789";

    function getColor() {
        var colorStr = "";

        for(var idx=0; idx < 6; idx++ ) {
                colorStr += hexChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * hexChars.length));
        }

        return colorStr;
    }

    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
            var rand = getColor();

            $('#myDiv').html('#' + rand).css({ 'background-color' : '#' + rand });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or he just shouldn't append `<br/>` when he assigns `info2`.

Comment: I changed my code to what you said it should read, but it still didn't work; it's not changing the background color, only displaying the text

Comment: @user3666355 It must be something else about your runtime context or scope that is preventing that from working.  Please see the working fiddler for a basic example.  I'm just mocking up the color string obviously.